# JQuery Coding Question?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm kind of new to JQuery i really don't know how to code in the `.hide()` so that it hides the following code from begin displayed until clicked `<li>Changes saved!</li>` and then have it fade in using the `.fadeIn`. Can some one show me how to code in the `.hide()` and `.fadeIn` correctly into my JQuery code?

Here is the JQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $(".save-button").click(function() {
        $.post($("#contact-form").attr("action"), $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(html) {
            $("div.contact-info-form").html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('<li>Changes saved!</li>');
        });
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey you confused me. :) The list item "Changes Saved!" wont appear until the button is clicked because it is being appended correct? So what are you hiding?

Comment: @thatryan, Well instead of appending it can I hide it? I told you I was new :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#changes-saved').append('<li>Changes saved!</li>').show().pause(1000).hide();
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that your submit button has the class of "save-button". If that is your button's name, you might want to do something like

```
$("save-button").click(function(){
```